# Android - How to make a contacts group invisible to whatsapp

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger

is it possible to create a contacts group in my Android that wouldn't be visible even to whatsapp "show inivisible contacts" ?

I mean, I don't want that group to appears in whatsapp what-so-ever

If not, is there any app that can easily hide (ie, remove a group from Android contacts) and unhide whenever you want?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not specific hope so. Do you want to hid yourself from certain friends who are in your contact list?

If so, then you can add them to block them in the block list. (But you will be still receiving the messages from them).

Or change your privacy settings in whatsapp according to your convince.

Answer (score 1):

This idea might be helpful:

1.Backup the contacts which you have hide it.

2.Delete those contacts from your people.

3.Now Synchronize the contacts and do refresh in Whatsapp. Now you got to see no contacts, I mean the contacts which you try to hide.

4.Available Possible ways : (A) Go to Settings > General > Accounts > Whatsapp > Untick the option. (B) In Whatsapp, Go to Menu Button > Settings > Contacts > Untick Show all contacts. (C) People > Menu > Accounts > Untick Auto-sync app data

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

Phone Settings >[image: IMG: Setting Phone sync] Whatsapp > [image: IMG: Setting Phone sync] People > [image: IMG: Setting Phone sync]

5.Reboot your Phone.

6.Now restore those contacts.

Answer (score 0):

> I mean, I don't want that group to appears in whatsapp what-so-ever

If this is made possible by WhatsApp, how are you suppose to send message to that group? If you cannot send the message, then what is point of having that group?

You may want to check the [WhatsApp FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/23776567) but AFAIK there is **no mention of Hiding** the group in Whatsapp.

If you do not want to send the messages from that group, you can simply exit the group

Another option is to [mute the group](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/23776567#mute). You will still receive messages sent to the group, but your phone will not vibrate or make noise when they are received.

If your only intention is to avoid "other people" from knowing which WhatsApp group you belong to, then you can use [Locking apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=lock%20apps) to achieve it.

> If not, is there any app that can easily hide (ie, remove a group from
>   Android contacts) and unhide whenever you want?

That group is specific to WhatsApp and is not known to other parts of Android system as well as to other apps.

It is very unlikely that WhatsApp will allow other app to operate(hide/unhide) on the User data belonging to WhatsApp. Not possible AFAIK.

Comment: I don't think the question is about groups inside WhatsApp, but about groups/categories of contacts in the Contacts/People app.

Comment: @DanHulme Shall I keep the post or better to remove? I assumed it to be for `whatsapp`

Comment: It's up to you, but I don't think it's relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Hide Contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nothingapps.com.secondarycontacts) could be what you are looking for. It can't be read by other apps and you can call or send message to a hidden contact, import contacts from the default app and it also has caller ID.
I was also looking for a similar app, didn't find it so I decided to develop one myself.